# Does the sensors work when smartphone is switched off and what can make sensors work incorrect?

Tags: samsung

We want to track the movement and location of employees based on information from the accelerometer and gyroscope sensors (there are some control points, but their number is very small, mainly tracking is based on sensors).
I want to understand what can affect the operation of the sensors and do they work when the phone is switched off? In order to understand possible ways how employees can outsmart the system.

Comment: What state is "switched off" in your opinion: a phone that has been shut down or a phone with a simply switched off screen?

Comment: @Robert  phone that has been shut down

Answer (score 1):

If the phone is really shut down then it is irrelevant if the sensors are working or not (typically I would assume that in device off-state the sensors are not powered).

Sensors provide real-time data. If no-one retrieves and saves it the data is lost.

Therefore in device off state no app is running to retrieve the data and thus no data can be collected (assuming the sensors really could work and are getting powered in device off state which I doubt).